# Asp.Net authentication(getting logout automatically)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my application I have used Asp.Net Form Authentication,

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                    1,
                    adminResult.UserName,
                    DateTime.Now,
                    DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
                    true,
                    "Administrator",
                    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
                    );
                string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                HttpCookie coockie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
                if (ticket.IsPersistent)
                {
                    coockie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                }
                Response.Cookies.Add(coockie);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Cockpit");
                }
```

But it's getting logout in 10 to 15 seconds automatically.

What would be the solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Please share you web.config details

Comment: <forms name="FXLWeb.ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Home" protection="All" path="/" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="false" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be because of the garbage collector clearing and re-assigning the machine key to your app. [Generate a machine key](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey) and place it in the web.config

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="###YOUR KEY HERE ###"
                decryptionKey="## decrypt key here ##" 
                validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

MachineKey is used for ViewState encryption and validation and the `FormAuthentication` uses this key to sign the auth ticket, if you dont specify one in the `web.config` it is automatically assigned, but if you yourself specify it the collector wont clear it...
[HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx#paght000007_machinekeyexplained) is an informative article it may help you understand better the importance/working of MachineKey

Comment: Thank you sir,
It works, does machine key fool the garbage collector. How machine key did the job, please reply.